# Google CSE (Custom Search Engine) different search button and fields?

Tags: search, pdf

I am getting some strange (to me) results when using Google CSE on my site.

Background:

The site has a MAIN search field (Google CSE #1 we'll call it)..  that was set up in the Google CSE admin panel.. and set to be a site wide search.

I recently added a page that will be the front end search for a directory of PDF's.

I went back to Google CSE admin page.. made a NEW entry for this PDF sub-directory..

pointed to only this directory and its child/sub-directories..
set it to ONLY return .pdf results..

outside of these two differences, both CSE accounts/entries are set-up identical.

The problem or question I have is..

the 'results' pages (while have the same exact settings, search field on top of results, full row...single page..etc)..are different a bit.

the 'new' page results has a tan colored 'ad block' on top of the results.. 
and 'more importantly' the results page SEARCH field itself looks different, and the SEARCH BUTTON itself looks different, and has an 'x' (close/clear) button right after it

if the settings are the same,.. how am I getting different looks? if only PDF file type or confined to a sub-directory for indexing/searching are different?.. do those settings somehow give different looking elements like that?

the new page SEARCH/SUBMIT button also have a magnifying glass on it. where original one has search text..

I didnt see anything in the "Look and Feel" section of the admin pages

what is affecting the different looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer: choosing hide ads or not under the BUSINESS section in Google CSE admin page changes the 'looks' of the search field & submit button...

why that should affect the visual results, I have no clue.